# cv2 not showing any thing

Tags: python, opencv, pygame

i am trying to use the laptop camera to take pictures and show the pictures, and i am using python 3.6.3 and windows 
i have tried to use the cv2 module and i have used this simple code

```
import  cv2
video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print ( video.read())
video.release()
```

and it only receives black picture , this is what i got form the print ( video.read()) :

```
(True, array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        ..., 
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        ..., 
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        ..., 
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       ..., 
       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        ..., 
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        ..., 
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        ..., 
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8))
```

i have tried different codes and i have tried to change `video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)` to `video=cv2.VideoCapture(1)` or to `video=cv2.VideoCapture(-1)`
and did not work when i changed it to 1 or -1 it printed (False , none) and also i am sure all my drivers don't need any update

is there is any other ways to take pictures from my laptop camera ? other then the cv2 and pygame ? as long as pygame camera only work for linux

Comment: On my laptop (a ThinkPad), I have to discard the first dozen or so frames before something, somewhere stabilizes and starts returning good results. what happens if you try that?

Comment: i have tried that also and nothing happend i have waited to half hour and its stayed black

Comment: as I know `CV2` uses `pygame` to get image from camera.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it and works without a problem:

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    if not video_capture.isOpened():
        print('Unable to load camera.')
        sleep(5)
        pass

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
```

What you have on the frame variable is your picture so you can save it to disk with something like:

```
cv2.imwrite("mypic.jpg",frame)
```

Comment: yes i have tried this and it just stay black no matter how long i wait 
is there is any other things i could use for python 3.6.3 to get images from laptop camera ?